# Can one offer a bounty for more rep than one has?

Tags: support, bounty

I noticed [this question](https://superuser.com/q/447522/128794) has a bounty on it for 100 rep, where the OP (at the time I'm writing this) has 67 rep.  What is the relationship between a bounty you can offer and the rep you have earned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rep is deducted as soon as you start the bounty. So he doesn't have it any more.

Comment: Well that just makes perfect sense :)